# Problema con formato de fechas

Tags: php, php7, datetime, cakephp

Estoy trabajando con el formato de fechas mas específicamente con la función de `php` **Time::createFromFormat()**

Tengo la siguiente linea de código:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data['fecha_ubicacion'])) {
     $this->request->data['fecha_ubicacion'] = Time::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',
     $this->request->getData('fecha_ubicacion'), 
     'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
}
```

El problema es que no me lo está guardando en la bd y me tira el siguiente error en la consola:

**Expected type 'DateTimeZone|null'. Found 'string'**

No sé bien que es ,alguien puede ayudarme?.

Gracias!

Comment: El error lo que te está diciendo es que en vez de usar el **string** "'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires" debes pasar a `::CreateFromFormat` un objeto de la clase **DateTimeZone**

Comment: Tienes algun ejemplo de como lo harias ,soy muy nuevo en esto gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como te decía en mi comentario, necesitarías hacer uso de un objeto de la clase **DateTimeZone** para que te funcione:

```
//Creamos la zona
$zona = new DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
//Definimos el formato
$formato = 'Y-m-d';
//Creamos el objeto Datetime con el ::createFromFormat pasándole el formato 
//y la zona además de la fecha
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, '2020-01-10', $zona);

echo "Fecha: " . $fecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```